# Can you 'click' loaded content in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-click-event

I am trying to create a page where the example div is clickable, as it would be below.

However I'm trying to make it so if the user clicks the logo it will reload the original content using load.

After this load has occurred is it possible to 'click' a loaded `<div id="example">`? I'm trying this at the moment and it fails to alert when clicking the loaded `<div id="example">` that is in file.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#example").click(function(){
        alert("You clicked me!");
    });

    $("#logo").click(function(){
        $("#main").load("file.php");
    });
});
</script>
    </head>

<body>
    <img id="logo" src="404.gif" />

    <div id="main">
        <div id="example">This is content.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

file.php contains

```
<div id="example">This is loaded content that can't be clicked?</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is that `.click()` only binds events to elements that exist in the DOM at that moment in time. Meaning that when you add a new element to the page, it will not have an event handler bound to it.

### Solution

If you're using jQuery 1.7+, rather than using `.click()` in your code use `.on()` instead.

```
$("#main").on('click', '#example', function(){
    alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

...or with older versions of jQuery use `.live()` instead:

```
$("#example").live('click', function(){
    alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

This will ensure that new elements added to the DOM will get the event handler bound to them also.

Comment: Your older version usage should call the `.live()` method rather than `.on()`.

Comment: This works well apart from if I have `$("#example").not("#random").on('click', function(){`, does the not part cause a problem?

Comment: Do your examples work? I seeing in the documentation that a selector is required for on or am I missing something?

Comment: @DarrylHein it does need a selector, but this doesn't have to be passed inside the `on` parens. See examples at the bottom here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Silver89 you can't use `not` I'm afraid ... from the docs - "DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector."

Comment: Think I found a solution `$("#main").on('click', "#example:not(#notme)", function(){`

Comment: Cool, I just found out that my 'on' syntax did infact need the additional child selector in order to delegate to 'live' - have updated my code sample accordingly

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$("#example").live('click',function(){
   alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

Comment: As per jquery 1.7, the live() method is deprecated. Use on instead

Comment: if you are using jQuery 1.7+ you can use `on` othervise you have to use `live`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you replace the innerHTML of `<div id="main">`, `<div id="example">` no longer has the click action on it.

There are a couple methods to solve this:

First and probably the best method is to use `.on()`:

```
$("#main").on('click', '#example', function(){
   alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

This attaches to `#main` and therefore, it doesn't matter what you do with the content inside. As the events bubble up, they will be noticed by the `on` and then the selector will determine if the handler should run.

Second there is live. The following will replace your current click on `#example`:

```
$("#example").live('click', function(){
   alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

The one flaw in this is that jQuery is constantly watching the dom for any changes, which depending on how many you'll have, this can start to slow things down (although maybe not noticeably on faster machines). Also, `.live()` has been deprecated in 1.7.

The last option is to add a success function on the `#logo` click. I'd recommend creating a method so you don't have duplicate code:

```
var example_click = function() {
    alert("You clicked me!");
};

$("#example").click(example_click);

$("#logo").click(function(){
    $("#main").load("file.php", example_click);
});
```

This means that every time after `#main` is loaded successfully, the click will be added to `#example`. But this is kind of ugly as you need to call the function twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery 1.7+, use "on".

http://api.jquery.com/on/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `click()` function for the `example` div in the callback for the load function.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.7 introduced the `.on()` API for event binding and event delegation:

```
$("#main").on("click", "#example", function() {
    alert("You clicked me!");
});
```