# Do the positives of using jQuery to load content outweigh the seo negatives?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, seo, navigation, load

I'm currently redesigning a site and considering whether or not too use .load for most navigation to make it faster for the user and just nicer to use.

To do this I have links with `<a href="/the/link" id="linkId">link</a>`

I then use `$("#main").on("click", "linkId"` with `return false` so that the links aren't followed.

I have /load/page.php and /page.php to supply either the load code needed or the full page version if a user is going straight to it.

Lastly on all load page changes I update the page hash using `document.location.hash = "/" + $(this).attr("href");`

This means urls of the site would look like the following to the users:

```
domain.com/#/file/page
```

and this to the search engines:

```
domain.com/file/page
```

If a user types in the hashed url they are redirected with the following code to the actual search engine url so I think I have everything covered?

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/, ""));
}
```

I'd block the hashed urls from being indexed and only allow the proper urls to be reached, I was then thinking if people linked to the hashed url would you need to do a page moved for seo?

Are there any massive disadvantages to this approach and/or are there better ways to go about it when trying to create fully dynamic sites?

Comment: what's the current site structure, like /file/page?  I'm asking because I don't recommend changing the url structure of an existing site

Comment: The site structure would stay exactly the same and the seo urls wouldn't change, the hashed urls would be new but search engines shouldn't ever see/be allowed to access them so it's okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't use two versions of php dispatcher. Instead, check if request is ajax, if so - serve the content only (otherwise, serve the full html - this should make the web crawlers still see the html version).

secondly, instead of providing different hrefs, use sth like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
      // load content of $(this).attr('href')
      // & change the hash
      return false;
  });
});
```

this will keep the site seo friendly (and also user-without-js - friendly ;) )

Have a look at http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

// -- added 18:45Z

if, for some reason, modifying the dispatcher is too complex or impossible, you might want to consider using jQuery's load filtering ability (see jQuery load docs), however that method produces unnecessary overhead and it's better to avoid it.

Comment: That's a very good idea, hadn't considered that, certainly makes editing etc simpler.

Comment: At the moment I'm using `$("#main").on("click", "linkId"` because the content is loaded and you can't 'click' loaded content [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515142/can-you-click-loaded-content-in-jquery could I do the same with $("body").on("click", "a"`

Comment: Silver89, if I understand correctly, what you need is 'live' method

Comment: If you use this method does it pose any sort of xss threat if users are allowed to post links within the site? Might be wise to always disallow any user generated external links than simply using a? I understand this is a general example but some users may copy and paste ..

Comment: @Silver89 sorr, I don't get it - how could it be more vulnerable than just 'static' page? :)

Comment: Well if someone posted a link in a comment form to http://domain.com/script-attac.xss, then this jquery would load that remote url into the page?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read how to make Ajax applications crawlable at Google -
 http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it correctly. This is basic progressive enhancement. If the user doesn't have access to js, then they get the static version regardless of what URL they access. If they do have js, then they get the ajaxified version.

Your method is proper, except that I'd follow @migajek's suggestion in regards to checking if the request is ajax. Here's on such solution: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax.

This way, you don't have to manage both the /load/page.php and page.php - just one.

Also, search engines won't index the hash part of the url, so you don't need to worry about blocking that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "hash-location update" the major browsers today support changing the entire URL without a page reload ([History Push State](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)), not just what comes after `#`.

You should implement that functionality, since:

1. The urls looks nicer
2. If a user posts a link on a forum/blog/whatever you want crawlers to associate the correct content with that link.

Link to more information regarding the matter:

- **[developer.mozilla.org - Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)**

---

> I'd block the hashed urls from being indexed and only allow the proper urls to be reached

The contents after the hash stays client-side, unless you send it to the server using javascript or something similar.

And since crawlers normally doesn't execute javascript or "something similar" it's impossible for you to check so that some `#key` doesnt get indexed by a web crawler.

---

### AJAX + SEO = No Biggie!

If you do it correctly there really will be no penalty from a SEO-perspective when using ajax to further please your visitors (and your backend servers).

Though you'll need to keep your head straight since there are some pitfalls a long the way, but if you pay attention everything will work out.